# Why Pre-send Script was cleared anytime job is executed?

Tags: jenkins

I config all jenkins job's Pre-send Script with below script:

```
for(job in Hudson.instance.items) {
    def list = job.getPublishersList()
    for (publisher in list) {
        if (publisher instanceof hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher) {
            def preSendScript = "your script here"
            publisher.setPresendScript(preSendScript)
        }
    }
}
```

After the script executed from script console, I found jobs' pre-send script was modified:
[image]

But when I ran the job, pre-send script did not work since it was cleared.

Why Pre-send Script was cleared anytime job is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config change was not saved.

We should use `job.save()` after `publisher.setPresendScript(preSendScript)`.

Working script should be:

```
for(job in Hudson.instance.items) {
    def list = job.getPublishersList()
    for (publisher in list) {
        if (publisher instanceof hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher) {
            def preSendScript = "your script here"
            publisher.setPresendScript(preSendScript)
        }
    }
    // must have
    job.save()
}
```